# How do I know the measurement units corresponding to a given locale?

Tags: c, localization, internationalization, locale, units-of-measurement

I'd like to display length in a locale-dependent way, i.e.: show the length in the correct measurement unit for the current locale. I know `LC_MEASUREMENT` is what I need to use, however how do I use it?

GNU gettext does not give me anything to work with `LC_MEASUREMENT`. I looked at the source of some weather applets and they all require you to manually enter your unit (Kelvin, Fahrenheit or Celsius) in the preferences window.

It seems to me that that environment variable is never used by anyone, however I'd really like to use it to give a better user experience. Perhaps, is there a free (as in freedom) database that maps locale names to the corresponding measurement units?

FYI: my application is written in C.

Comment: Huh. Good question. I was expecting that quick look at Glibc, ICU, the CLDR, or GNU units would find an answer. I was disappointed that none of these sources seems to have such a database. The CLDR provides translations for the names of three measurement systems; "US", "UK", and "Metric". Perhaps you should assume these are the three choices: just use US units in the US, use metric units in the UK except for road distances (which are in miles), drinks (which are in pints), and body height and weight (inches and stone), and metric everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the C standards and GNU gettext do not offer any way to know the measurement units used in a country, there are no third party libraries that do the job and there are no ready to used databases (free or proprietary).

However, according to [CIA - The World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/references/weights-and-measures/):

> At this time, only three countries - Burma, Liberia, and the US - have not adopted the International System of Units (SI, or metric system) as their official system of weights and measures.

So it is fairly easy to write your own code, even without a database or third party libraries. You just have to special case three `LC_MEASUREMENT` values (or, better, three patterns, as some of these countries have more than a language):

- [Burma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma#Units_of_measure) (language code pattern: `*_MM`) uses the [Burmese system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_units_of_measurement);
- [Liberia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberia#Measurement_system) (language code pattern: `*_LR`) uses the [Imperial system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units);
- [United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States#Measurement_systems) (language code pattern: `*_US`) use a [customary system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units) similar to the Imperial one.
- all other countries use the [International System of Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).

**UPDATE:** all of these countries are in the (*slow*) process of converting to the metric system (SI). This is probably an another reason why nobody has bothered writing some libraries, code snippets or databases.

Comment: The UK is also a holdout. As I mentioned in my comment above, they use miles for road distances (and speedometers), pints for drinks (beer, milk, etc), stone for weight, and frequently inches for height as well. While they do officially use the metric system for many other measurements, they have these few traditional exceptions. See [Metrication on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication) for more details. Also note that due to proximity to the US, Mexico and Canada frequently use US units (or both US and Metric).

Comment: This is funny. Many people may be like me, who are curious to see that CIA World Factbook, but are afraid to click it. Ahaha. If you think alike, +1 feedback. And to satisfy your curiosity, I clicked it it gave me a 404 (link is broken). So, don't bother. Now I'm being tracked for your safety. Sometimes you take one for the team.

Comment: @DrBeco Way to go. :-)  Seriously, though, the *World Factbook* is a great resource.  Updated link: https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/

Comment: oh boy! I just read the hidden question about C unions in your profile @SteveSummit. Hilarious. But now I'am even more afraid of CIA and Unions.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but there is another way. If not a definitive solution, at least a good workaround.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <langinfo.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        /* for LC_MEASUREMENT */
        const char *nonmetric="_MM _US _LR";
        char *measured;

        printf("NL_MEASUREMENT: %s\n", nl_langinfo(_NL_MEASUREMENT_MEASUREMENT));

        measured=getenv("LC_MEASUREMENT");
        printf("\nLC_MEASUREMENT: %s\n", measured);
        has_=strchr(measured, '_');
        if(has_!=NULL && strstr(nonmetric, has_) != NULL)
            printf("US Customary Units\n");
        else
            printf("Metric System\n");

        /* for LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_MESSAGE, LC_CTYPE and others */
        struct lconv *lc;

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8");
        lc=localeconv();
        printf("\nLC_MONETARY, Currency symbol: %s\n", lc->currency_symbol);
        printf("\nLC_NUMERIC, Decimal point: %s\n", lc->decimal_point);
        printf("\nLC_MESSAGE, YESEXPR: %s\n", nl_langinfo(YESEXPR));
        printf("\nLC_CTYPE, CODESET: %s\n", nl_langinfo(CODESET));
    
        return 0;
    }
```

(*) The second block of code is there just for completeness.

But the first part of the example gives the information available about the metric units. It is not much, but it is currently what is at your disposal.

It just identifies the country code. But you can test it against these 3 [countries](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-countries-use-the-metric-system.html) (Myanmar/Burma, the United States, and Liberia):

- *_MM (my_MM or en_MM)
- *_US (chr_US, HAW_US, en_US, es_US or lkt_US)
- *_LR (ff_LR, kpe_LR or en_LR)

and if it is different, you can assume the metric system is adopted (or at least partially adopted).

---

Call this program without environment variables to see your configuration:

```
$ ./lc_measurement.x

NL_MEASUREMENT: UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT: C.UTF-8
Metric System

LC_MONETARY, Currency symbol: R$
LC_NUMERIC, Decimal point: , 
LC_MESSAGE, YESEXPR: ^[+1SsyY]
LC_CTYPE, CODESET: UTF-8

$ LC_MEASUREMENT="kpe_LR" ./lc_measurement.x

NL_MEASUREMENT: UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT: kpe_LR
US Customary Units

LC_MONETARY, Currency symbol: R$
LC_NUMERIC, Decimal point: , 
LC_MESSAGE, YESEXPR: ^[+1SsyY]
LC_CTYPE, CODESET: UTF-8
```